# How to get document id from firestore database

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve a document id by calling `doc.getId()` but I can't call it from this code

```
        db.collection("Pegawai").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if(e != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                }
                if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {
                    for (DocumentChange doc: queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                        if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                            Pegawai pegawai = doc.getDocument().toObject(Pegawai.class);
                            pegawai.setId(doc.getId());
                            pegawaiList.add(pegawai);

                            pegawaiListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I've tried this code, and apparently, I can call `doc.getId()` with this code, but this code isn't populating my `recyclerview` at all

```
        db.collection("Pegawai").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if(e != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                }
                if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        Pegawai pegawai = doc.toObject(Pegawai.class);
                        pegawai.setId(doc.getId());
                        pegawaiList.add(pegawai);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [DocumentChange](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentChange) object has a method [getDocument()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentChange.html#getDocument()) which returns a [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot.html) object.  This is a subclass of [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html) which means it also has a [getId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getId()) method.  So you should be able to use `doc.getDocument().getId()` to get the ID of the document being processed.

Comment: I get it working by creating a method to load my data and call it whenever a data is changed and it's like a roundabout way. But the `getDocument()` method works like a charm! I didn't think it was that simple

Answer (score 2):

If you are using FirestoreRecyclerAdapter with Recyclerview do this.

```
 DocumentSnapshot snapshot = options.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position);
            String dbKey = snapshot.getId();
            Log.d(TAG, "The database Key is : "+ dbKey);
```

Then you can bind it on view holder like this

```
    holder.setDocumentId(dbKey);
```

Then you can you retrieve it anywhere, depending on your getters and setters. I hope this will help someone out there.

Comment: You can also do this, You will get a unique value everytime!    String _key = db.collection("requests")
                            .document()
                            .getId();

Answer (score -1):

The following is how to solve it in Javascript, maybe this will help you to convert it to Java.
Using the following method, we can retrieve the document id, dynamically. Notice that we use `snapshotChanges()`. This is important because once we subscribe to this function, contained in the subscription is the document id.

```
saveMyValuesHere: any[] = []

getPegawai() {

    return this.db.collection('Pegawai').snapshotChanges();

  }

 getPegawai().subscribe(serverItems => {
      this.saveMyValuesHere = [];
      serverItems.forEach(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        this.saveMyValuesHere.push({ id, ...data});
      });
    });
```

Comment: The question is tagged with Java, and showing Java, but you're showing JavaScript.  This might not be helpful to them.